# I would like to turn on an LED when another circuit is closed - but unpowered. How can I do this?

Tags: led, resistors

I have several transistors controlling several small motors which are under 30 ohms. I'm trying to indicate whether there's a motor attached or not using LEDs, so each circuit will either be low resistance (<30 ohms) or high resistance (megaohms). I want the LED to turn on when there's low resistance and off when there's high resistance, whether or not the transistor is on.

Is there any clever circuit for this or am I better off measuring the resistance with a microcontroller and using an LED driver? I'm hoping to avoid having a bunch more parts than I strictly need, especially given that I need to have a relatively high number of indicator lights.

Thanks

Comment: It's simple if you didn't add the requirement that the LED be *on* even when the motor is switched *on* by the transistor. Just an LED and resistor in parallel to the transistor would do that. But given the requirement, you may need a separate supply (AC or DC) just to observe the motor's presence separately from when it is active.

Comment: By switching my transistors from high side to low side, this works great, and I just now realized I can put a second LED connected to the base of the transistor to indicate when it's currently active. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just glad it helped. Thanks for letting me know. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (adjust values to suit whatever your voltages may be):

[image: Tenth South South Forum on Sustainability - THINKING NEW HORIZONS (7 - 30 July 2023)]

The comparators can be 1/2 of a quad or a dual. I've chosen R1 to drop 100mV nominally at full motor current. It also has to withstand start-up surges. Some protection on the inputs may be necessary such as series resistors. Flyback diode not shown. R2 represents the motor.

The 0.05 and 6V = Vcc/2 voltages can be created by one pair of voltage dividers for many comparators since the comparators hardly load the sources.

The LED is on for the motor present whether powered or no, and off if there is no motor. It's an 'OR' of (motor current present) + (motor off but motor resistance < R3)